# Importing an Excel file from Teams Sharepoint into Python with error: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sharepoint

I am trying to read an excel file from SharePoint to python and I get the following error:

*ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually*

My Code:

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File 

url_sp = 'https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/TeamE'
username_sp = 'MyUsername'
password_sp = 'MyPassword'
folder_url_sp = '/Shared%20Documents/02%20Team%20IAP/06_Da-An/Data/E/Edate.xlsx?web=1'

#Authentication
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url_sp)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username_sp, password_sp):
    ctx = ClientContext(url_sp, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print('Authentication sucessfull')

else:
    print(ctx_auth.get_last_error())
    
import io 

response = File.open_binary(ctx,folder_url_sp)

bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) 

data = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj,sheet_name = None)
```

Can it be related to the fact that the Excel file consists of several worksheets?
Can you help me further?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Several Sheets should not be a problem. Have you tried specifying an engine in your code like the error message says ?

`data = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheet_name=None, engine= ... )`

Possible options can be found in the documentation of pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) (scroll down to `engine: str, default None`). The explanation

> If io is not a buffer or path, this must be set to identify io

seem to fit your fit your problem